# How to get timezone by utc offset?

Tags: java, timezone-offset

I have the UTC offset -05:00, I want to get timezone names by offset.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of("-05:00");
System.out.println(offset.getId()); //prints -05:00
```

I want to get the result like this :

```
America/Chicago
America/Eirunepe
Etc/GMT+5
Mexico/General 
...
```

I want time zones that are at offset `-05:00` right now (not those that may be at another time of year).

Comment: I mean, what is your limit to whether you admit legitimacy of existence of all sovereignty nuts that say that they live in a time zone that's GMT minus 5 hours? Does your list need to include Kumesadom/kumegrad5, which I guarantee is GMT-5, except during its two daylight saving time periods (varies on whether the year is leap according to Julian calendar)? I guess you first need to start a time zone database and start an open invitation for interested parties to register to it.

Comment: ZoneOffset is a sublass of ZoneId and it deals with the offset as its name suggests not with time zone names. The parent however can return the name. Try super.getId()

Comment: Do you want time zones that are at offset -05:00 right now? Those that are at some time of year? Those that have been at some point in history or will be at some time in the future?

Comment: I want time zones that are at offset -05:00 right now.

Comment: I hesitated a bit before upvoting the question since it doesn’t show a research effort or your own attempt to solve it. It’s an interesting question, though, asked regularly, but seldom as clearly as here. So I upvoted in spite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it, check this out.

```
final List<ZoneId> timeZoneByUtc = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().stream().map(ZoneId::of)
        .filter(z -> z.getRules().getOffset(Instant.now()).equals(ZoneOffset.ofHours(-5)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It seems to work. And nice application of a stream. I wouldn’t dare rely on `==`, though, I’d use `.equals()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-05:00");
        String a[] = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(tz.getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

O/P

America/Atikokan
America/Bogota
America/Cancun
America/Cayman
America/Coral_Harbour
America/Detroit
America/Eirunepe
America/Fort_Wayne
America/Grand_Turk
America/Guayaquil
America/Havana
...

Comment: Incorrect answer. Detroit, Fort Wayne, Grand Turk and Havana are at −04:00 at this time of year. Also when the asker is using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, don’t give an answer using the long outdated `TimeZone` class.

Answer (score 1):

First determine when is “right now”: use `Instant.now()` (if you want a consistent answer, call `Instant.now()` only once).

Then iterate over all available time zones and include those that are at offset -05:00 right now. First get available time zone IDs as strings from `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`. For each get the corresponding `ZoneId` object from `ZoneId.of(String)`. There are different ways to obtain the offset right now. One is `yourZoneId.getRules().getOffset(rightNow)` (where `rightNow` is your `Instant`). This gives you a `ZoneOffset` object that you can compare to your `offset` from the question using `.equals(Object)`.