# Get timeZone information from date with date with offset value

Tags: java, date, time, zone

we have the below date having offset -07, which belong to `"US/Pacific"` time zone.

```
String startTime = "2020-06-12T09:30:00.000-07:00";
```

I want to retrieve timezone info (`"US/Pacific"`) from above date object.

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't have any information about a time **zone** in this `String`, it just tells you the **offset** of `-07:00`. This offset is not unique or exclusive for `"US/Pacific"`.

Comment: @deHaar what if i want to get all timezone info, this particular offset belongs to

Comment: Do you want to find all time zones having that offset at that very moment?

Comment: @deHaar yes thats right

Comment: Similar: [How to get timezone by utc offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51045064/how-to-get-timezone-by-utc-offset)

Answer (score 4):

You can get a list of zones that have a -7h offset at that particular moment in time, but it will not be unique. For example you could use this code:

```
String bookingStartTime = "2020-06-12T09:30:00.000-07:00";
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(bookingStartTime);
Set<String> allZones = new HashSet<>();
for (String z : ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()) {
  ZoneId id = ZoneId.of(z);
  ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant(id);
  if (zdt.getOffset().equals(odt.getOffset())) allZones.add(z);
}

for (String z : allZones) System.out.println(z);
```

And the output is:

> US/Pacific-New
>   America/Tijuana
>   SystemV/PST8PDT
>   US/Arizona
>   America/Santa_Isabel
>   Canada/Yukon
>   Canada/Pacific
>   America/Creston
>   America/Phoenix
>   America/Dawson_Creek
>   America/Los_Angeles
>   America/Whitehorse
>   America/Ensenada
>   America/Dawson
>   PST8PDT
>   America/Hermosillo
>   America/Vancouver
>   SystemV/MST7
>   Etc/GMT+7
>   America/Fort_Nelson
>   US/Pacific
>   Mexico/BajaNorte

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the `String` to an `OffsetDateTime` (knows offset only), extract the `ZoneOffset` from it, use it to compare a `ZonedDateTime` (knows zone and offset) for every available `ZoneId` with this offset and store the ones with equal offsets.

The following method gives you a list of possible `ZoneId`s for an `OffsetDateTime` parsed from the `String` you have:

```
private static SortedSet<String> getAllZoneIdsFor(OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime) {
    // initialize a data structure for the result
    SortedSet<String> result = new TreeSet<>();
    // extract the zone offset from the given OffsetDateTime
    ZoneOffset zoneOffset = offsetDateTime.getOffset();

    // then check all available zone ids for a matching offset
    for (String zone : ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()) {
        // create a ZoneId object from the string
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(zone);
        // create a ZonedDateTime from the given LocalDateTime adding the zone
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = offsetDateTime.atZoneSameInstant(zoneId);
        // and check if the extracted offset equals the one of the current zone
        if (zonedDateTime.getOffset().equals(zoneOffset)) {
            // and add the zone id to the result if it does
            result.add(zoneId.toString());
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

You would use it in a `main()` like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // take the offset dateime string
    String bookingStartTime = "2020-06-12T09:30:00.000-07:00";
    // parse it to an OffsetDateTime
    OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(bookingStartTime);

    // get the zones with the offset of the given OffsetDateTime
    SortedSet<String> matchingZones = getAllZoneIdsFor(offsetDateTime);
    // and print them all
    matchingZones.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

and see the output

```
America/Creston
America/Dawson
America/Dawson_Creek
America/Ensenada
America/Fort_Nelson
America/Hermosillo
America/Los_Angeles
America/Phoenix
America/Santa_Isabel
America/Tijuana
America/Vancouver
America/Whitehorse
Canada/Pacific
Canada/Yukon
Etc/GMT+7
Mexico/BajaNorte
PST8PDT
SystemV/MST7
SystemV/PST8PDT
US/Arizona
US/Pacific
US/Pacific-New
```

Please note you won't be able to find a particular `ZoneId` just providing an offset. You would need more information (e.g. the system locale) in order to determine a specific zone for a given offset.