# How to store ZonedDateTime of java in TIMESTAMPTZ in oracle?

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone, zoneddatetime

I want to store the ZonedDateTime in TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE datatype in oracle.
If I am trying to store string directly as a String it throws not a valid month.
then I found that I can convert it to the TIMESTAMPTZ in java then store because we need to convert the string to TIMESTAMPTZ and its throwing error.

```
String d = "2021-10-28 02:36:08.000000 +02:00";
TIMESTAMPTZ t = new TIMESTAMPTZ(con, d);
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setObject(1,t);
```

Error/stack trace:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
>   at java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(Timestamp.java:251)
>   at oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ.toBytes(TIMESTAMPTZ.java:1919)
>   at oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ.<init>(TIMESTAMPTZ.java:253)
>   at OracleSelectQuery.main(OracleSelectQuery.java:21)
> ```

Someone please look into this.

Comment: After [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69451932/how-to-convert-a-2021-09-29t170431-0000-0530-to-2021-09-29-170431-0000000) I am tempted to ask whether you just want to save the UTC offset (+02:00) or you need to save a time zone (like for instance Europe/Paris)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The three-arg TIMESTAMPTZ(Connection, Timestamp, ZoneId) constructor

According to the documentation of the Oracle `TIMESTAMPTZ` class (link at the bottom) it has a constructor that in addition to the connection takes a `java.sql.Timestamp` and a `java.time.ZoneId` as arguments (a funny mixture of an outdated and a modern Java class). Since we can extract a `ZoneOffset` from your string and `ZoneOffset` is a subclass of `ZoneId`, we can use this constructor for your purpose:

```
    String d = "2021-10-28 02:36:08.000000 +02:00";
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(d, PARSER);
    Instant inst = odt.toInstant();
    ZoneId offsetAsZoneId = odt.getOffset(); 
    TIMESTAMPTZ t = new TIMESTAMPTZ(con, Timestamp.from(inst), offsetAsZoneId);
```

I used this formatter for parsing:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter PARSER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
        .appendLiteral(' ')
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
        .appendLiteral(' ')
        .appendOffsetId()
        .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);
```

### You may also save a time zone to Oracle

That the constructor I used accepts a `ZoneId` opens the additional possibility that we may store a real time zone ID like Europe/Paris or Asia/Kolkata to the database rather than just a naked UTC offset. At least the way I read the Oracle database documentation, its `timestamp with time zone` data type can hold a time zone ID. The example given in the documentation is America/Los_Angeles.

For a simple example of converting a `ZonedDateTime` to a `TIMESTAMPTZ`:

```
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
    Instant inst = zdt.toInstant();
    ZoneId zid = zdt.getZone(); 
    TIMESTAMPTZ t = new TIMESTAMPTZ(con , Timestamp.from(inst), zid);
```

### Links

- [Documentation of `TIMESTAMPTZ`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jajdb/oracle/sql/TIMESTAMPTZ.html) and its [`TIMESTAMPTZ(Connection, Timestamp, ZoneId`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jajdb/oracle/sql/TIMESTAMPTZ.html#TIMESTAMPTZ-java.sql.Connection-java.sql.Timestamp-java.time.ZoneId-) constructor.
- Oracle database *Datetime Data Types and Time Zone Support* help, section [Datetime and Interval Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#i1005946). Scroll down to *TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE Data Type*.

Comment: Thanks, Resolved the issue,
I used this way

Answer (score 3):

### *java.time*

The [following table](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) depicts the mapping of ANSI SQL types with `java.time` types:

| ANSI SQL | Java SE 8 |
| --- | --- |
| DATE | LocalDate |
| TIME | LocalTime |
| TIMESTAMP | LocalDateTime |
| TIME WITH TIMEZONE | OffsetTime |
| TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE | OffsetDateTime |

Parse the given Date-Time string into `OffsetDateTime` as shown below:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS XXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String strDateTime = "2021-10-28 02:36:08.000000 +02:00";
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-10-28T02:36:08+02:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/iSNqiX)

Now, you can store this `OffsetDateTime` into the database as shown below:

```
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (columnfoo) VALUES (?)");
st.setObject(1, odt);
st.executeUpdate();
st.close();
```

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Comment: Thanks, Resolved the issue
Though I have used bit different ways